# python: import com.oceanoptics.omnidriver.api.wrapper.Wrapper

Tags: python, dll, import

I am trying to import the following api wrapper / device driver as in this [python package](https://code.google.com/p/python-microscopy/source/browse/Acquire/Hardware/Spectrometer/remoteSpectrometer.py?spec=svn103e7d36c67411cb7ca38ea749b9796e40ec1fef&r=103e7d36c67411cb7ca38ea749b9796e40ec1fef):

```
import com.oceanoptics.omnidriver.api.wrapper.Wrapper
```

Python just returns that there is no module named like this:

```
ImportError: No module named com.oceanoptics.omnidriver.api.wrapper.Wrapper
```

I installed Omnidriver from the device manufacturer's [website](http://www.oceanoptics.com/Technical/softwaredownloads.asp). Specifically, I used the installer OmniDriver-2.37-win32-installer.exe and installed the "Development version". It installs a bunch of dlls in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ocean Optics\OmniDriver\OOI_HOME`.

The wrapper is working properly in Matlab after adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ocean Optics\OmniDriver\OOI_HOME` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\local\librarypath.txt` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ocean Optics\OmniDriver\OOI_HOME\OmniDriver.jar` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\local\classpath.txt`. Thereafter, I can load the wrapper in Matlab with `wrapper = com.oceanoptics.omnidriver.api.wrapper.Wrapper()`.

I guess my python installation (Enthought Canopy 1.4.1 win 32bit) is not looking for the dlls in the correct path because I would have to tell first.

So, my question is, how do I instruct python to successfully execute the import statement above?

Comment: It would be useful to explain how you installed the Omnidriver.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As requested, I added details on the installation process, the solution in Matlab and the installed python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for interfacing to the spectrometer using Python would be to use the [python-seabreeze](https://github.com/ap--/python-seabreeze) package. The package does not have thorough documentation, but if you're willing to be patient and try things out for yourself, then you should be able to get it to work. The author has put considerable work into making the package compatible with the vast majority of Ocean Optics' spectrometers. I just finished installing it on my Windows laptop and got it to work in under an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website, and can't find any reference to python support. I believe the instructions you referenced are instructions how to install the java classes. I could find no information that mentioned or discussed python modules. You should contact Oceanview for clarification.

Comment: I think they don't support it officially, but the first link in my question suggests that it is possible somehow. The instructions for editing the search path are for matlab, which again is written in java. I am looking for an aequivalent in python.

Comment: Your unlikely to get any kind of useful help from StackOverflow. I checked the link, and it is a really complicated (and very domain specific) solution, with dozens of pre-requiesites. I recommend you move your questions over to http://python-microscopy.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/index.html. Sorry.

Comment: (however) let me throw you one suggestions. If you can actually FIND the compiled python module (probably *.pyd), you can try adding the path of where it exists to your sys.path before attempting the import.